# CSS: Using transition for paragraphs causes text to tremble

Tags: html, css

There is a sample code available. Please run it.

When you hover your mouse over text, you see a tremble or distortion (I don't know what it's called) in text.

This problem occurred in other situations besides `transition:scale`.

In general, I would like to know what the source of the problem is and how I can solve it.

```css
div {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  
}

div:hover {
    transform: scale(0.98);
}
```

```html
<div >
    <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes the distortion, but you can use `font-size` instead of `transform: scale`

```css
div {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  
}

div:hover {
    font-size: 3.52rem;
}
```

```html
<div >
    <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's a little better, but it's not perfect

Answer (score 0):

it's the scale value that is causing this with text it's not very optimised, try this:

```
div {
transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 50% 50% 50%;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
div:hover {
transform: scale(0.9) translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it has not been resolved

Comment: Try this instead: I added `translate3d(0,0,0)`to the hover effect, as well as `backface-visibility` and that seems to help, though now, the final frame of the effect stays blurry. Better than having the text re-render on animation end.

Answer (score 0):

you need to describe that what type of transition you need on hover.. simply change the font-size in hover and your transition will work ..
as

```
div {
font-size: 3.6rem;
transition: all 0.3s;
```

}

```
div:hover {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

<div >
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is different than changing font size, I want to scale it

Comment: For scaling you need to fix width or height that you want to scale . As you know that the block element already has 100% width so make it smaller in width to scale the width in transition